# Locate name doesn't work

Tags: locate

There is a file at `/user/share/jogl.jar`.

I am using `locate jogl.jar`

but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the man page:

```
   locate  reads  one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes
   file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs  to  standard  output,
   one per line.
```

Run `updatedb` as root and try again. It should work.

Alternatively you can use `find` or `find | grep`, which does not uses a db (and thus is considerably slower).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?  Two main issues come to mind, if you're not familiar with `locate`, both related to the fact that `locate` relies on a database and *not* directly on the file system.

1. **It doesn't display any result**: in this case, you might need update `locate`'s database by simply running `updatedb` from a terminal
2. **It returns way too many results**: once again, `locate` uses a database, not the current directory (contrary to several other common unix commands), so if you try to locate `somestuff` from your `home` directory in order to find all the `somestuff` that it might contain, it won't work.  You'll have to run it with the full path instead: `locate ~/*somestuff`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Ubuntu didn't add me, as a user, to the group that's allowed to read the default database. The solution was:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mlocate YOUR_USER_NAME
```

This information was learned by reading `man updatedb` and examining the permissions of the default db in `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.